# For which $u$ in $\mathbb R^2$ does the directional derivative exist?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I would like to know if I answered this question correctly.

> Define $f$ by $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
> $$
> f(x,y) = \frac{x^{2} \sin y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{4}} \text{ and } f(x,y) = 0 \text{ for } (x,y) = (0,0)
> $$
> For which $u \in R^{2} \text{ without } {0}$ does the directional derivative $(D_{u}f)(0,0)$ exist?

My attempt:

$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0+tu,0+tv)-f(0,0)}{t} = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{t^{2}u^{2} \sin t^{2}v^{2}}{t^{3}u^{2}+t^{5}v^{4}} = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{u^{2} \sin v^{2}}{tu^{2}+t^{3}v^{4}}
$$
Since this limit does not exist because we are dividing by 0 if $t \rightarrow 0$, so for no $u \in R^2 \text{ without } 0$ does the directional derivative exist.

Comment: `$\sin$` creates $\sin$.  Otherwise, $sin$ looks like the multiplication of three terms $s$, $i$, and $n$.

Comment: A limit including a division by $0$ can of course exist, though.  It happens every single time when you take a derivative, for example.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I am pretty stuck with my limit, can you tell me how to go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are OK up to this point:
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{t^{2}u^{2} \sin t^{2}v^{2}}{t^{3}u^{2}+t^{5}v^{4}} .
$$
But then
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{t^{2}u^{2} t^{2}v^{2}}{t^{3}u^{2}+t^{5}v^{4}}\;\frac{\sin t^{2}v^{2}}{t^2v^2}
=
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\; t \;\frac{u^2v^2}{u^2+t^2v^2}\; \frac{\sin t^{2}v^{2}}{t^2v^2}
= 0\;v^2\;1 = 0 .
$$

Comment: So I think I understand where I went wrong.  $$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{t^{2}u^{2} \sin 
 t^{2}v^{2}}{t^{3}u^{2}+t^{5}v^{4}} = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{t^{4}u^{2} \sin v^{2}}{t^{3}u^{2}+t^{5}v^{4}} = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{tu^{2} \sin v^{2}}{u^{2}+t^{2}v^{4}} = \frac{0}{u^{2}} = 0$$ So the directional derivative existst for every $u \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ \{0}

Comment: @illegalsh yeah you dropped a $t^2$ when you did the division.